# How i find xpath or css for below ui element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

[image]I am facing one issue. I need to find one single any username but cant't able to locate element with any locators from those 
 tags. I tried //*[@id="login_credentials"]/h4 or //[@id="login_credentials"]/text()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNaN5.png)  but not able to extract any user_id from above list.

```
public class pr1 
{   
  @Test
  public void Test1() throws InterruptedException
  {
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
      WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
      String str=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login_credentials\"]/text()[1]")).getText();
      System.out.println(str);
   }    
}
```

[image: This error is occured during running the testI nedd to find this username]

Comment: Please share a link to that page, not a picture if you want us to help you

Comment: https://www.saucedemo.com/   Please check this link

Answer (score 0):

All those texts: "standard_user", "locked_out_user", "problem_user" and "perfor" are text content of `"//*[@id='login_credentials']"` element. So, applying `.getText()` method will return all these strings.
You can extract all these values and after that to split it into substrings with regular `split()` method.